# How to change IP Address every few seconds with TOR in Linux

Tags: configuration, anonymity, linux, ip-address

I want to know if I can configure TOR on Linux to change / rotate IP every 30 seconds or say X seconds . 
I have tor setup but I don't want to keep browsing with same IP and want to change it every few seconds.

Comment: It automatically changes every 10 minutes. There is no way to alter this in Tor Browser.

Comment: it possible with a simple shell program!
write a bash script to restart tor service within a loop with fixed time

Answer (score 1):

You could modify "/etc/tor/torrc" or in "path/to/your/torbrowser/Data/Tor/torrc" to cycle proxies faster:

MaxCircuitDirtiness NUM

Answer (score 0):

Just Restart the TOR for getting fresh IPs in any amount of time.
Eg. I developed this script in Linux to change my IP for every hit over the target site for scraping it.

Bash:
//////

- while true
- do
- service tor start
- python3 scraper.py
- service tor stop
- done

//////

So, It was changing the IP for every hit over the target site.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please don't use the tor network for website scraping. It makes the network worse for everyone else.

Comment: I understand! But it's life my friend... Buying proxies is very expensive. That's why people use TOR for the same. At last, everything is done to earn money and people have to minimise all the investment costs. I agree with you on your part. But please suggest a better way so, it can make a change.